# TeamCity and FXCop version 10

Tags: teamcity, fxcop

We are trying to get our TeamCity 5.1 installation to use our FXCop project file.  It apparently does not like the newest version, V10:

```
[08:26:33]: Failed loading FxCop project.
[08:26:33]: Error text: This project file is version 10.0 but the current application version is 1.36. Please download a more recent version of FxCop to open this file..
[08:26:33]: Process exited with code 1
```

Is there a way to upgrade the version that TeamCity uses or do I need to downgrade the version we are using on our workstations?

Does anyone know if TeamCity 6 will support FXCop 10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to change the [FxCop installation root](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/FxCop) on the FxCop Build Runner tab. You'll want to install FxCop 10 on the build server/agents first, or put it under source control and use a VCS root (beyond the scope of this question).

Side note: [Tip for installing FxCop 10](https://web.archive.org/web/20130828154445/http://blogx.co.uk:80/ViewItem.asp?Entry=812).

Comment: You are exactly right. I feel like a dummy for not realizing that the buildagent had FXCop, not the build server. Your answer got me working. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TrueWill, Your side note link is broken

Comment: @shanabus Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

TrueWill had the right answer. I wanted to add that I had to do the following to get it working:

1. Install FXCop 10 (You can get it from the 7.1 Windows SDK)
2. Update buildagent.properties to include:

   system.FxCopRoot=C:\Program Files\ (x86)\Microsoft\ Fxcop\ 10.0

   system.FxCopCmdFileVersion=10.0.30319.1

   system.WindowsSDK7.1
3. Restart build agent.1.

Comment: where are the bbuild agent properties specified?  Is it something set with the build definition or on the build server?

Comment: @Tedford - there is an FxCop path setting (automatic/manual) in the FxCop Build Step settings.